# android - navigating frm 1 screen to anothr, done using Intent but eclipse gives some error

Tags: android, android-intent

0

in my case i hav to navigate frm 1 screen to nthr aftr the timer is completed ... i hav 2 classes named test.java and test2.java!! inside Test.java class i hav created a class named Timer and in that in onFinish() method wen i write

startActivity(new Intent(this,Test2.class)); finish();

eclipse shows an error "The constructor Intent(test.MyTimer, Class) is undefined"

what shall i do??

Comment: ya its not giving any compile time error....
thanks....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to use a context class when you create an intent

use your parent class there

```
startActivity(new Intent(myParentClassName.this,Test2.class)); 
finish();
```